# OJS 3.4 Failed to initialize plugin: pkpTags Error: editor.addButton has been removed in tinymce 5x

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, tinymce, ojs

I have upgraded OJS 3.3.0.14 to 3.4.01, removed some incompatible plugins but I am stuck with a tinyMCE issue. When I click on the button to assign a reviewer to a submission, I get the error these 2 errors

```
Failed to initialize plugin: fullscreen Error: editor.addMenuItem has been removed in tinymce 5x, use editor.ui.registry.addMenuItem instead
```

and

```
Failed to initialize plugin: pkpTags Error: editor.addButton has been removed in tinymce 5x, use editor.ui.registry.addButton or editor.ui.registry.addToggleButton or editor.ui.registry.addSplitButton instead.
```

I have cleared both template and data caches in OJS but the problem still persists.

Below is the complete message from firefox

```
XHRGET
https://example.com/index.php/ijch/$$$call$$$/grid/users/stage-participant/stage-participant-grid/add-participant?submissionId=4210&stageId=3&_=1692021299284
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 614ms]

GET
https://example.com/plugins/generic/tinymce/plugins/pkpTags/plugin.js
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

XHRGET
https://example.com/index.php/ijch/$$$call$$$/grid/users/user-select/user-select-grid/fetch-grid?submissionId=4210&stageId=3&_=1692021299285
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 596ms]

GET
https://example.com/plugins/generic/tinymce/plugins/pkpWordcount/plugin.js
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

GET
https://example.com/lib/pkp/lib/vendor/tinymce/tinymce/plugins/fullscreen/plugin.min.js
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

Failed to initialize plugin: fullscreen Error: editor.addMenuItem has been removed in tinymce 5x, use editor.ui.registry.addMenuItem instead
addMenuItem https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:309
c https://example.com/lib/pkp/lib/vendor/tinymce/tinymce/plugins/fullscreen/plugin.min.js:1
https://example.com/lib/pkp/lib/vendor/tinymce/tinymce/plugins/fullscreen/plugin.min.js:1
PN https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
IN https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
Re https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
IN https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
UN https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
eH https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
Re https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
a https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
loadScript https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
Re https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
loadScripts https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
loadQueue https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
eH https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
p https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
KN https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
Re https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
a https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
loadScript https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
Re https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
loadScripts https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
loadQueue https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
KN https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
eH https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
nH https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
render https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:309
initializeTinyMCE https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:106
jQuery 2
initializeTinyMCE https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:105
FormHandler https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:209
parent https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:93
AjaxFormHandler https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:218
parent https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:93
StageParticipantNotifyHandler https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:361
parent https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:93
b https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:91
objectFactory https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:89
pkpHandler https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:373
jQuery 2
pkpHandler https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:373
https://example.com/index.php/ijch/workflow/index/4210/3#workflow line 2 > injectedScript:4
jQuery 11
https://example.com/index.php/ijch/workflow/index/4210/3#workflow line 2 > injectedScript:2
jQuery 6
success https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:373
jQuery 6
pkpAjaxHtml https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:373
modalOpen https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:293
ModalHandler https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:279
parent https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:93
AjaxModalHandler https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:292
parent https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:93
b https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:91
build.js:305:943998
Failed to initialize plugin: pkpTags Error: editor.addButton has been removed in tinymce 5x, use editor.ui.registry.addButton or editor.ui.registry.addToggleButton or editor.ui.registry.addSplitButton instead
addButton https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:309
https://example.com/plugins/generic/tinymce/plugins/pkpTags/plugin.js:25
PN https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
IN https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
Re https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
IN https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
UN https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
eH https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
Re https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
a https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
loadScript https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
Re https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
loadScripts https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
loadQueue https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
eH https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
p https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
KN https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
Re https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
a https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
loadScript https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
Re https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
s https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
loadScripts https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
loadQueue https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
KN https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
eH https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
nH https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:305
render https://example.com/js/build.js?v=3.4.0.1:309
initializeTinyMCE https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:106
jQuery 2
initializeTinyMCE https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:105
FormHandler https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:209
parent https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:93
AjaxFormHandler https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:218
parent https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:93
StageParticipantNotifyHandler https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:361
parent https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:93
b https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:91
objectFactory https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:89
pkpHandler https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:373
jQuery 2
pkpHandler https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:373
https://example.com/index.php/ijch/workflow/index/4210/3#workflow line 2 > injectedScript:4
jQuery 11
https://example.com/index.php/ijch/workflow/index/4210/3#workflow line 2 > injectedScript:2
jQuery 6
success https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:373
jQuery 6
pkpAjaxHtml https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:373
modalOpen https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:293
ModalHandler https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:279
parent https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:93
AjaxModalHandler https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:292
parent https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:93
b https://example.com/js/pkp.min.js?v=3.4.0.1:91
build.js:305:943998
GET
https://example.com/lib/pkp/lib/vendor/tinymce/tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

GET
https://example.com/lib/pkp/lib/vendor/tinymce/tinymce/skins/ui/oxi

de/content.min.css
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

GET
https://example.com/plugins/generic/tinymce/styles/content.css
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

GET
https://example.com/plugins/generic/tinymce/plugins/pkpTags/styles/editor.css
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

GET
https://example.com/lib/pkp/styles/fonts/noto-sans-v11-vietnamese_latin-ext_latin_greek-ext_greek_devanagari_cyrillic-ext_cyrillic-regular.woff2
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
```